# Create a function with a class Player with values "username" set to input, "size" to 50, "x" and "y" to 0

Tags: java, function, class, return

Trying to create a function with a class Player with values "username" set to input and the rest set to numbers. Searched a few websites but the answers weren't really helpful

Current code:

```java
Player createPlayer(String un) {
    class Player{
    String useruname = un;
    int size = 50;
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    }
    return class Player;
}
```

Error: illegal start of experssion (line 7)

Comment: First, `return class Player;` is not valid Java. From your method signature, it looks like you want to return an **instance** of `Player`. That would look like `return new Player();`. But that still won't quite work. You've declared `Player` as a _local class_ (i.e., inside a method). You can't have a local class as the return type of the method. You should probably be defining `Player` as either a static nested class, or a top-level class (in its own source file). That will likely involve creating a constructor as well.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the class should probably look something like this:

```
public class Player {
    private String username;
    private int size;
    private float x;
    private float y;

    public Player(String un) {
        username = un;
        size = 50;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
}
```

First of all, when you're creating a new class in Java, you need to make sure it's in its own file, named according to the name of the class (for example, this code would be in a file called `Player.java`. As for the code itself, you'll notice that I first declared the variables `username`, `size`, `x`, and `y` without assigning them values. In Java, it's common to declare a class's instance variables like this, and assign them values later (although it's up to personal preference).

You'll also notice that I didn't include a function that returns a `Player` instance. This is because, in Java, you can use a *constructor* instead. The constructor for this Player class is the method beginning with `public Player(String un)`. Constructors look very similar to regular methods, but instead of starting with a return type and a name, they simply start with the name of the class. The constructor of a class is called whenever a new instance of that class is created, so it's perfect for setting an instance's initial values. In this case, the `Player` constructor sets the values of `size`, `x`, and `y` to preset integer values. Since you can pass arguments to constructors, it also sets the value of `username` to the `un` argument, which can be specified every time a new player is created.

To create a new instance of the player, it's just like creating a new instance of any other class, except you need to pass in all of the arguments that you specified in the constructor method. For example,

```
Player myPlayer = new Player("MyUsername");
```

will create a new instance of the `Player` class called `myPlayer`, which has the username `"MyUsername"`.

Hope this helps!